# Is it possible to open a new native webbrowser by Javascript in my existing webview?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, webview

```
<a href="http://the-page-i-want-to-jump" 
target="_blank"> <%= image_tag ("banner_bb_en.png", :alt => "",
:style => "width:100%;") %> </a>
```

It's a my server-side code. When I click the image in a blackberry webview, it jumps to new page inside webview. But I'd like to change this to jump with opening a new native webbrowser which associated to default browser.(I shouldn't modify the client code, now)
Is it possible?

Comment: isn't this a general mobile (security) setting ?

Answer (score 2):

With some options, javascript popups can do it!
But in server side, i don't think PHP can be that.

look at popups : http://www.blazonry.com/javascript/windows.php